# Serilog - How to roll over after every 8 hours?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have the following code, which rolls over logs everyday:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.File(path: "C:\\WRS\\log-.txt",
                outputTemplate: "Time:{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information
             )
            .CreateLogger();
```

However, I would like to set the roll over to every 8 hours instead of every day. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I would like to set the roll over to every 8 hours instead of
> every day. Is this possible?

At present, it seems that it is impossible.

If you check the RollingInterval enum value, you can see that it contains `Minute`, `Hour`, `Day`, `Month`, `Year`, and `Infinite`.

[image]

From these threads: [Precise rolling interval](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/213) and [Added Week to the RollingInterval enum.](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/pull/182) We can see that the Serilog Develop team has not planned to add this kind option to set the granular rolling intervals.

So you can have to use `RollingInterval.Day` or `RollingInterval.Hour`.